# How to use a4j:mediaOutput correctly for displaying images?

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

Using the code below I can't get the image in the web page. I'm not sure if I understand the documentation in the right way and I'm not able to find any problem with this code.

`BEAN`

```
@ManagedBean(name = "imageBean")
@RequestScoped
public class ImageBean {
    public void paint(OutputStream os, Object data) throws IOException {
        BinaryContent content = (BinaryContent) data;
        BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(content.getContent()));
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", os);
    }
}
```

`PAGE`

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{dataProviderBean.aoRequests}" var="item">
    <f:facet name="noData">No messages are available.</f:facet>
    ...
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Image data</f:facet>
        <rich:list value="#{item.imageContents}" var="content">
            <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" cacheable="false" session="false"
                createContent="#{imageBean.paint}" value="#{content}" />
        </rich:list>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If someone will have the same problem in the future, here is the solution:

The `content` I put into `value` attribute is an object which holds binary data of a image. Because it is serialized in URL, the length is too big and it does not work. You have to pass some `id` and fetch the object in the paint method.

`Example`

```
<rich:dataTable value="#{dataProviderBean.aoRequests}" var="item">
    <f:facet name="noData">No messages are available.</f:facet>
    ...
    <rich:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Image data</f:facet>
        <rich:list value="#{item.imageContents}" var="content">
            <a4j:mediaOutput element="img" cacheable="false" session="false"
                createContent="#{imageBean.paint}" value="#{content.id}" />
        </rich:list>
    </rich:column>
</rich:dataTable>
```

`BEAN`

```
public void paint(OutputStream os, Object data) throws IOException {
    String id = (String) data;
    BinaryContent content = (BinaryContent) getContentById(id);
    os.write(content.getContent());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

ImageBean use @SessionScoped or @ApplicationScope https://community.jboss.org/thread/168523