# Show images from inputsstream in xhtml page

Tags: database, image, jsf, servlets, inputstream

I need to show some images that queried form database and placed into inputstream.My framework is JSF and I know that by using servlet, I can show them. But the problem is that there is many images in my page that placed into database, now if I want to select each image from database and show in my xhtml page, a lot of queries needed. In one managedbean, all of images placed into List of inputstreams, and I want to show each element as an image in page. In fact my requirement is to read image from inputstream and show in xhtml page.Can any body guide me?

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Richfaces, you can use `<ui:repeat>` to iterate your list of images and use `<a4j:mediaoutput>` to show your images on your xhtml, [example](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/mediaOutput.jsf?tab=usage&cid=267499), also see [How to use a4j:mediaOutput correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677207/how-to-use-a4jmediaoutput-correctly-for-displaying-images)
and another [example](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_mediaOutput.html)

Comment: I don't use richfaces. There is no other solution?

Answer (score 0):

> *now if I want to select each image from database and show in my xhtml page, a lot of queries needed*

How exactly does that form a problem? Have you measured the performance? Is the bottleneck *really* in "a lot of queries"? I really don't understand why that would form a bottleneck. It should be blazing fast with a properly designed datamodel, a self-respected SQL database is designed for exactly this purpose.

Isn't your bottleneck *actually* the step of making a DB connection and that you're doing that on *every single* query because you aren't using a connection pool? If so, then yes, it would be understandable that it would perform very slow. Making a DB connection can be as slow as 100~500ms. That's exactly why connection pools were invented a long time ago. Connections would then only be initialized and cleaned during "idle time" and shared/reused on a threadsafe manner and thus getting a connection from it should be no more than 10ms or something.

If you fix your data layer to utilize a decent connection pool, then you can keep using your servlet which is **already** the right tool for the particular job.

Comment: You guess correctly. There is no connection pool in my application and this is the reason of bottleneck in database. Thanks for your attention. So if I understand, there is no way to use one connection for all of the images. Is it correct?

Comment: The connection pool handles that transparently. It'll reuse one connection for different queries/transactions as long as possible.

Comment: Thanks dear BalusC, I will modify connection to DB